# Free SMS messages sent to mobile phones outside

Tags: rest, sms

Does anybody know some kind of service which can send or/and recieve text messages using REST API? The implementation I am trying to built must use a code snippet that makes the sent request to the server in order to send the message to a phone number.

Some examples:

- [www.twilio.com](http://www.twilio.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are plenty of them if you made a search, and most are free for certain number of pushes per month/days/hours/minutes/seconds and if you want increase that number you may pay some fee. All these services they usually are using api  along with web interface and it is easy to work with!

Some examples:
http://www.freesmsgateway.com/

Comment: Thanks,

can you tell One of them?

Comment: http://www.freesmsgateway.com/